# Should the mold tag be defined and divided?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [mold](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mold) tag is used for two totally different type questions. Currently there are 56 questions tagged mold, 51 refer to the fungus and 5 refer to the piece of equipment used to form a particular shape.

It appears as though more questions could be tagged with mold (equipment). I started running through the [equipment](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) tag in the first 100 questions there were at least 2 that could use the mold tag, but hadn't used it.

Or, should the tag be defined for the fungus and removed from the equipment questions?

Comment: Ambiguous tags aren't great, but removing a tag is bad too - ideally we should come up with distinct names for the two meanings.

Comment: "moulding" and "mould-growth"?